# To find the difference between two times

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I want to get the difference between two times.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setCurrentQuestion];
}


-(void)setCurrentQuestion{

    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    startTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTime];

    [self answerTapped];  
}

-(void)answerTapped{
            endtime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
            date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endtime];
            [dateFormatter release];
            dateFormatter = nil;

            NSTimeInterval * timeDifference =[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];


}
```

I am using this code to get the difference between start time and end time, but I am getting the error as " Inintializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double*') " at "NSTimeInterval * timeDifference =[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]; " line. What this error means? How to resolve this? Or Please tell me how will I get the time difference? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the asterisk.  You are declaring timeDifference as a pointer to an NSTimeInterval.  It's just a double as you correctly point out.  Just change to:

```
NSTimeInterval timeDifference =[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

Also, I think your dates and strings are getting released too early. The simplest thing to do is to declare properties for your dates.  For pre-ARC:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate * date1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate * date2;
```

or for ARC:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * date1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * date2;
```

Then assign with a dot operator like this:

```
self.date1 = [NSDate date];
```

You don't need those strings at all.

Comment: Thanks Danh. I got your point, but I am not getting the time difference as my program receives 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'. Can you please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think you need those strings at all.  When you want to record the start time, set date1=[NSDate date];, when you want to mark the end, do the same with date2.  Your timeDifference line looks fine.  My guess on your crash is a premature release of date1.  Can I see the declarations of the dates and strings?

Comment: Yes sure.Here it is,   NSString * currenttime;
    NSString * endtime;
    NSDate *date1;
    NSDate *date2;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

Comment: @hgpl, I think your dates and strings are getting released.  I'm going to edit my answer to show you code.